# json string decoding encountering invalid escape

Tags: python, json

I am using `simplejson` to decode the following json string.

Here is a demo written in Python:

```
from simplejson import loads

loads("""["\s"]""")
```

The decoder will throw:

```
JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape
```

How to cope with this? The expected output is:

```
["\\s"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"\s" is not a valid JSON escape string.

According to [json.org](http://www.json.org/), only the following escape are valid

- \"
- \\
- /
- \b
- \f
- \n
- \r
- \t
- \u *four-hex-digits*