# ValueError: Invalid \escape: When readin json as respons in Scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

During parsing i get text object response with json in it. They all look very much alike. And some of them work without any errors. But others throw an error as below.

I tried to use `replace('\r\n', '')` and `, strict=False.` To no avail.

Here is the URL i get json from  - [enter link description here](https://www.tripadvisor.com/UserReviewController?a=mobile&r=434622632)
Here is my code. (Line 51 is `data=json.loads`)

Also when i try this url in scrapy shell it opens up empty and throw another error - no json document located. Do not know if this is important.

```
def parse_jsn(self, response):
        #inspect_response(response, self)

        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['text']= data[0]['bodyfull']
        yield item
```

Here is the error code.

```
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 4 column 942 (char 945)
2017-03-25 17:21:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET
or.com/UserReviewController?a=mobile&r=434622632> (referer: https://www.tripa
w-g60763-d122005-Reviews-or490-The_New_Yorker_A_Wyndham_Hotel-New_York_City_N
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in it
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", l
der_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", l
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py",

    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", lin
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Code\Active\tripadvisor\tripadvisor\spiders\mtripad.py", line 51,
    data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode(), strict=False)
  File "c:\python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 352, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
  File "c:\python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 4 column 579 (char 582)
```

Comment: Are you sure unicode is the right encoding?

Comment: @Explosion Pills I am not. just googled for how to handle json in Scrapy. What options do i have? and how do i know the right encoding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixing invalid JSON escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15198426/fixing-invalid-json-escape)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, **+1** for scraping the mobile API. Much more clever than scraping from HTML!

Indeed there is a issue with the encoding.There are some octal encoded characters (`[...] \074br/\076\074br/\076Best Regards,\074br/\076Emily [...]`) that breaks the JSON parsing. To get rid of them use:

```
response.body.decode('unicode-escape')
```

Also there are some encoded HTML characters in the data: `"&#x201c;Nice clean and perfectly average&#x201d;"`. I suggest to unescape them:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
...
json.loads(HTMLParser().unescape(response.body.decode('unicode-escape'))
...
```

In Python 3:

```
import html 
...
json.loads(html.unescape(response.body.decode('unicode-escape')))
```

The result should look like: `[{'title': '“Nice clean and perfectly average”', 'bodyfull': '[...] stay. <br/><br/>Best Regards,<br/>Emily Rodriguez", [...]}]`

As you see, there is some HTML tags in the result. If you want to remove the HTML tags you could use a RegEx like:

```
import re
...
p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
no_html = p.sub('', str_html))
```