# ValueError: Invalid \escape: error while doing json.loads()

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am scraping a website and it has this JSON data in return.

https://pastebin.com/R50eTqrD this is output of `print( repr( string ) )`
https://pastebin.com/VH6JrDMG this is output of `print( string )`

I am doing

```
resp = json.loads(resp)
```

But its giving me this error

```
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 170 (char 169)
```

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43020017/4094231) and it suggested me to do

```
resp = json.loads(HTMLParser().unescape(resp.decode('unicode-escape')))
```

But it now throws this error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 51-59: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried several solutions like

```
json.loads(HTMLParser().unescape(resp.decode('unicode-escape')).encode("utf-8"))
```

and many more but none of it worked for me.

Comment: @user2864740 ok thanks for pointing out but with invalid json eror should be different ... my main goal is to solve this error `ValueError: Invalid \escape:` ... any idea how to do it

Comment: What's the *raw* JSON from the server? (ie. as per a browser web capture?)

Comment: @user2864740 `Tomáš Linhart`'s answer worked for me

Comment: This question definitely doesn't have a [example].

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with those `\x3E` characters in the string. If `s` holds the string, try this:

```
json.loads(s.replace(r'\x3E', '\x3E'))
```

Comment: What's "wrong" with `\x3E`? - Please provide codepoint values/escapes if relevant for disambiguation.

Comment: Ohh raw string vs normal.. got it.. the JSON source is encoding as `\x3E` (invalid/broken) and not `\u003E` (valid JSON encoding).. I wonder if it might return `\xZZ` for other values of ZZ in the future.

Comment: Can you please add a little explanation in the answer?

Comment: @Umair JSON parser gives exact position where it encounters an error - *char 169*. I looked at that part of the string and saw those characters. JSON probably can't unescape it so I replaced the escape sequence with the actual character.