# Adding variables to dataclass from json config file

Tags: python, json, python-dataclasses, ansi-escape

After watching [ArjanCodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRVVyl9uaZc) video on dataclasses,

I've been trying to add variables to a python dataclass from a json config file to format the font style of a print function printT in Jupyterlab.

I use ANSI escapes for the formatting which doesn't work anymore if I import the variables to the dataclass. Instead of formatting the text, the ANSI code get's printed out.

```json
# config.json
{
    "lb" : "\n",
    "solid_line"  : "'___'*20 + config.lb",
    "dotted_line" : "'---'*20 + config.lb",
    
    "BOLD" : "\\033[1m",
    "END" : "\\033[0m"
}
```

```py
# config.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json

@dataclass
class PrintConfig:
    lb : str
    solid_line  : str 
    dotted_line : str 

    BOLD : str
    END : str 
        
def read_config(config_file : str) -> PrintConfig:
 
    with open(config_file, 'r') as file:      
        data = json.load(file)      
        return(PrintConfig(**data))
```

```py
# helper.py
from config import read_config

config = read_config('config.json')

def printT(title,linebreak= True,addLine = True, lineType = config.solid_line,toDisplay = None):
    '''
    Prints a line break, the input text and a solid line.
        
    Inputs:
    title     = as string 
    linebreak = True(default) or False; Adds a line break before printing the title 
    addLine   = True(default) or False; Adds a line after printing the title
    lineType  = solid_line(default) or dotted_line; Defines line type 
    toDisplay = displays input, doesnt work with df.info(),because info executes during input
    '''
    if linebreak:
        print(config.lb)

    print(config.BOLD + title + config.END)

    if addLine:
        print(lineType)

    if toDisplay is not None:
        display(toDisplay)
```

```py
# test.ipynb

from helper import printT
printT('Hello World')
```

## Output

```
\033[1mHello World\033[0m
'___'*20 + config.lb
```

## Desired result

**Hello World**

---

It works if I use eval `if addLine: print(eval(lineType))` but I'd like to get deeper insights into the mechanics here. Is there a way of getting it to work without eval?

Also this part `"solid_line"  : "'___'*20 + config.lb"` feels wrong.

[Markdown as alternative to ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46934204/7031021)

Comment: If you’re voting to close for lack of clarity how about providing some feedback as to what you find unclear?  Me I can understand title’s apparent intent well enough but not much the actual body and sample code. Not VTC because I see it as salvageable, possibly.

Comment: Advice.  Forget json and config reading.  Minimalize the code to just your problem. For example, hardcode a dictionary showing what you’re trying to do.   Set values on an **instance** of a dataclass?  Extend the dataclass somehow?

Comment: I edited the question I hope it's clearer now. Thanks for the advice about the not using json and config reading. I am still curious though why the string is not evaluated and the text not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This string consists of an actual backslash followed by the digits `033`, etc.

```
"BOLD" : "\\033[1m",
```

To turn on bold on an ansi terminal, you need an escape character (octal 33) followed by `[1m`. In Python, you can write those escape codes with a single backslash: `"\033[1m"`. In a json file, you must provide the unicode codepoint of the escape character, `\u001b`. If the rest is in order, you'll see boldface.

```
"BOLD" : "\u001b[1m",
"END" : "\u001b[0m"
```

As for the `eval` part, you have a string containing the expression you need to evaluate. I assume you wrote it this way because you first tried without the double quotes, e.g. ,

```
"dotted_line" : '---'*20 + config.lb,
```

and you got a json syntax error.  That's not surprising: Json files are data, not code, and they cannot incorporate expressions or  variable references.  Either place your config in a python file that you include instead of loading json, or move the dependencies to the code. Or both.

In a python file, `config.py`:

```
config = {
    "lb": "\n",
    "solid_line"  : '___'*20,
    ...
```

In `helper.py`:

```
...
if addLine:
    print(lineType + config.lb)
```

Comment: I get this error ```JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 13 column 15 (char 341)``` if I use one backslash. I added a second one per [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65910282/jsondecodeerror-invalid-escape-when-parsing-from-python)

Comment: Oh oops, right, forgot about that. Write `\u001b` for the escape character in json, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020094/how-should-i-escape-strings-in-json). Or if you switch to a python config file, you can still write `\033`. (Edited my answer to fix it.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic configuration system.  I won't add the output since it would need a screenshot but it works on bash/macos.  [Inspired by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/287934)   and [tip_colors_and_formatting]

And from (https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting):

> In Bash, the  character can be obtained with the following syntaxes:
>
> \e
> \033
> \x1B

`\e` didn't work, so I went on to use to `\x1B` since that worked in the linked SE answer. `\033` works too, I checked.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

PREFIX = "\x1B["

#these aren't configurable, they are ANSI constants so probably
#not useful to put them in a config json
CODES = dict(
    prefix = PREFIX,
    bold = f"1",
    reset = f"{PREFIX}0m",
    red = "31",
    green = "32",
)

@dataclass
class PrintConfig:
    bold : bool = False
    color : str = ""

    def __post_init__(self):
        
        # these are calculated variables, none of client code's
        # business:
        self.start = self.end = ""
        start = ""

        if self.bold:
            start += CODES["bold"] + ";"

        if self.color:
            start += CODES[self.color.lower()] + ";"

        if start:
            self.end = CODES["reset"]
            #add the escape prefix, then the codes and close with m
            self.start = f"{CODES['prefix']}{start}".rstrip(";") + "m"

    def print(self,v):
        print(f"{self.start}{v}{self.end}")


normal = PrintConfig()
normal.print("Hello World")

bold = PrintConfig(bold=1)
print(f"{bold=}:")
bold.print("  Hello World")

boldred = PrintConfig(bold=1,color="red")
print(f"{boldred=}:")
boldred.print("  Hello bold red")

#this is how you would do it from json
green = PrintConfig(**dict(color="green"))

green.print("  Little Greenie")



#inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/287934
print("\n\ninspired by...")
CSI = "\x1B["
print(CSI+"31;40m" + "Colored Text" + CSI + "0m")
print(CSI+"1m" + "Colored Text" + CSI + "0m")
```