# What does \s denote in JSON?

Tags: json

I thought that `\s` denoted white space. But when I run it through JSON is parses as 's':

```
JSON.parse('["and you can\'t escape thi\s"]')
>>>["and you can't escape this"]
```

What does \s denote in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

This should help. [json string decoding encountering invalid escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480148/json-string-decoding-encountering-invalid-escape)
\s isn't a valid escape sequence at all in JSON. Without more context it's difficult to provide any further explanation.